# Asus ux31a- I cant boot and I lost some options from the bios.

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

Ok, here is a little bit long story. ( sorry for the bad English ).

laptop info:
asus ux31a
windows 8 64x pre installed 
windows 10 64x for now

bios info
Aptio 
American Megatrends
version 2.15.1227

I tried to install Ubuntu from a USB but with having ASUS that come with pre installed windows 8 that is updated to 8.1 is little bit hard. I went to a store and he told me its gonna cost me $100 to do so I said I will try my self. I tired a lot but the UEFI drove me crazy. I kept playing around and don't ask me what I did in bios I don't have any Idea. I tried to dual boot Ubuntu and windows 8 but I couldn't so I deleted windows 8 and installed Ubuntu alone. there was some problems like the font was so small and actually everything else. I couldn't figure out the problem. I tried to install windows 8 back and I cant now I believe there is options in my bios that gone or you can say that they are not there anymore. boot options for creating paths and naming the path is not available. what I want to do now is installing windows 8 and partition my drive so i can have three options one for windows and the second for Ubuntu and the third for experiments. can you guys help me ? and by the way, I cant access my windows 10 anymore. whenever I turn on my laptop its go directly to the bios.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4mIgcqleRUYTU1BUTdNN1B4cjg/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4mIgcqleRUYbW9leGhZZmJUTG8/view?usp=sharing